# Magento 2 adding jquery in home page

Tags: magento2, jquery

I have added 'jquery-1.10.2.min.js' in app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\default.xml file for showing a pop up on clicking Add to Wishlist button for product in home page. But on including custom js, the default 'Add to Cart' , 'Remove Item' is not working in My Wishlist section. Is it possible to include js file only for home page by removing the file default.xml

The following is my default.xml file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>

    <script src="vendor_Module::js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>

    <script src="vendor_Module::js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"/>
    <script src="vendor_Module::js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"/>
    <script src="vendor_Module::js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"/>

    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: you have to use inside cms_index_index.xml file

Comment: Use link instead of script tag in declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create **`cms_index_index.xml`** file to declare js inside your hompeage,

```
Using cms_index_index.xml file You can display all js inside Homepage only.
```

Your xml path would be below,

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\cms_index_index.xml file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>

    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>    
    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"/>
    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"/>
    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"/>

    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: I have included the above content in app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\cms_index_index.xml file. On viewing page source of the home page, the js files are not included. I am getting an error in console as 'ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'

Comment: Have your js file path,  app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js?

Comment: I have included the js file in  app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\

Comment: please remove var folder from root and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command. Also remove your browser cache

Comment: Still I am not able to see the js files added in my custom module on viewing the page source

Comment: change in above xml file vendor_Module to Vendor_Module

Comment: Is it possible to include js through backend cms->pages in layout section

Comment: The vendor name is in caps itself

Comment: I have checked same thing in my system its working fine.